# GetThreadContext() returning 87

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to get the thread context of suspended WordPad. However, no matter what changes I make to the code, it returns 87.

```
STARTUPINFO si = { 0 };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = { 0 };
CONTEXT ctx;

if (CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\write.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
{
    cout << "-> Success <-" << endl;
}

else
{
    cout << GetLastError();
}

if (GetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &ctx))
{
    cout << "-> Success <-" << endl;
}

else
{
    cout << GetLastError();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried: `If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.`?

Comment: *The value of the ContextFlags member of this structure specifies which portions of a thread's context are retrieved.* but you not init this member.

Comment: Race condition `CreateProcess`:  _"...Note that the function returns before the process has finished initialization. ..."_  source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: fyi Error 87 is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`

Comment: and `STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) }` must be - `CreateProcess` fail probably ?

Comment: @RichardCritten - no any *Race condition* if we create process with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` - get context at this point absolute correct

Comment: @RbMm: WAT? [*"Note that the function returns before the process has finished initialization."*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) This is still true even if `dwCreationFlags & CREATE_SUSPENDED`. The *only* thing `CREATE_SUSPENDED` does is prevent the call to `NtResumeThread` near the end of `CreateProcessW`. So it only causes `CreateProcessW` to return "sooner" (doing less things). It still returns before the process is fully initialized.

Comment: @conio - can i ask - how process initialization related to thread context ? for what you write all this unrelated things ?

Comment: @RbMm: You can ask whatever you want. The question is does it make any sense. Richard Critten cited what he *thought* was a problem: That `CreateProcessW` returns before the process has finished initializing. Your answer was that **if** we create the process with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` there's no race. This is both unrelated and wrong. The fact stated in the documentation is true regardless of `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and it's not a problem even without `CREATE_SUSPENDED`, without any ifs.

Comment: @conio - here absolute no any raise . when we create process with `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag - it (first thread) even not begin execute in user mode. until we not resume thread. so before this we can safe query thread context. and how this related to process initialization ? what you at all mean under this ? kernel mode initialization ? it complete when `CreateProcess` return. user mode initialization ? it yet not begin. and again - for how initialization here related at all ? we query thread context. which is absolute defined.

Comment: @RbMm: I mean initialization in the sense the MSDN and the Windows Internals books mean. Guess which one is it. Also, by definition, if initialization hasn't started as you say, it obviously couldn't finish...

Comment: @conio - i can not understand. question was about **thread context**. how process initialization (in any sense) here related ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155196/discussion-between-conio-and-rbmm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `CONTEXT` structure contains processor-specific register data. so it definition depend from target architecture. say for *x86* and *amd64* the different `CONTEXT` definitions.

here exist 32-64 bit issue in 64bit windows:

- 64-bit application can get 64-bit context of any thread by call
  [`GetThreadContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362(v=vs.85).aspx)
- 64-bit application can get 32-bit context of *WOW64* thread by call
  [`Wow64GetThreadContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681665(v=vs.85).aspx). note in this case you need use
  [`WOW64_CONTEXT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681670(v=vs.85).aspx).
- 32-bit application can get only 32-bit context of *WOW64* thread by
  call [`GetThreadContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362(v=vs.85).aspx)
- when 32-bit application try get context of thread in 64-bit
  application - the [`GetThreadContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362(v=vs.85).aspx) always failed with
  `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`

so based on your error i can say that you running on 64-bit windows. here *write.exe* is 64-bit process and your code is 32-bit. you can not get context in this case.

also, as general note we always must init `ContextFlags` member of `ctx`. this is mandatory:

> The function retrieves a selective context based on the value of the
>   **ContextFlags** member of the context structure.

so when *ContextFlags* is undefined - `GetThreadContext` return undefined result

so code must be next:

```
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi ;

    if (CreateProcess(L"C:\\Windows\\write.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi))
    {
        union {
            CONTEXT ctx;
#ifdef _WIN64
            WOW64_CONTEXT wow_ctx;
#endif
        };

        BOOL fOk = FALSE;
        BOOL Wow;
#ifdef _WIN64
        if (IsWow64Process(pi.hProcess, &Wow))
        {
            if (Wow)
            {
                wow_ctx.ContextFlags = WOW64_CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS|WOW64_CONTEXT_CONTROL|WOW64_CONTEXT_INTEGER;
                fOk = Wow64GetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &wow_ctx);
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS|CONTEXT_INTEGER|CONTEXT_CONTROL;
                fOk = GetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &ctx);
            }
        }
#else
        BOOL MyWow;
        if (IsWow64Process(NtCurrentProcess(), &MyWow) && IsWow64Process(pi.hProcess, &Wow))
        {
            if ((MyWow != 0) ^ (Wow != 0))
            {
                //32-bit app can not got context of 64-bit app
                SetLastError(ERROR_GEN_FAILURE);
            }
            else
            {
                ctx.ContextFlags = CONTEXT_DEBUG_REGISTERS|CONTEXT_INTEGER|CONTEXT_CONTROL;
                fOk = GetThreadContext(pi.hThread, &ctx);
            }
        }

        if (!fOk)
        {
            DbgPrint("error=%u\n", GetLastError());
        }
#endif
        ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I've tried setting the context flags, and have gotten the same result unfortunately.

Comment: @DennisFlores - understand - your process is wow64 process (32-bit process in 64 bit windows). and *write.exe* is 64-bit process. he simply have no 32 bit context

Comment: Thank you, very high quality answer. Stackoverflow never fails to disappoint. I feel embarrassed I didn't know that Notepad was x64 hahah

Comment: @DennisFlores - *windows\write.exe* and *windows\system32\write.exe* is 64 bit in 64 bit windows. but here exist *windows\syswow64\write.exe* which is 32bit